# sqlglot - Why is not able to parse correctly DELETE SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, parsing

Why Python module **sqlglot** is not able to parse correctly **DELETE** SQL Statement?

```
import sqlglot

sql="DELETE FROM MySchema.MyTable WHERE MyCol='MyValue'"

parsed=sqlglot.parse_one(sql)
```

Result:

```
parsed

(COMMAND this: DELETE, expression:
  (LITERAL this:  FROM MySchema.MyTable WHERE MyCol='MyValue', is_string: True))
```

Why **sqlglot** is capable of parsing the other DML commands (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE) but not DELETE?

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DELETE parsing is only partially supported as of v1.24.2. We interpret it as a command and parse the rest. I haven't really had a need to parse DELETE and so support is not fully functional.

EDIT: As of v1.24.3, SQLGlot now supporst DELETE FROM

```
(DELETE this:
  (TABLE this:
    (IDENTIFIER this: MyTable, quoted: False), db:
    (IDENTIFIER this: MySchema, quoted: False)), where:
  (WHERE this:
    (EQ this:
      (COLUMN this:
        (IDENTIFIER this: MyCol, quoted: False)), expression:
      (LITERAL this: MyValue, is_string: True))))
```

Comment: Hi Toby Mao,
It is really a pitty because I am using your module sqlglot in my project and it works fine with the other DML commands (SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE) but I also need the support to DELETE command.
Is it something that you could consider to include?
DELETE command syntax is really easy compared to the other commands...

Comment: Yes, I can add it easily, maybe in a couple days, or you can make a PR.

Comment: @FMoreira this is now supported in v1.24.3

Comment: Thanks a lot Toby Mao.
You are the man... :-)

I confirm that it is working exactly as expected.
Keep up the good work.